Defining column width as a fraction of linewidth/textwidth in tabularx and tabularray
I would like to create a table with the first column being exactly 0.5\linewidth (or 0.5\textwidth) and then a series of l and X columns, i.e. adjusted to the contents or adapting to the remaining space.
I tried doing this using both tabularx and tabularray, but the right edge of the left column never quite seems to be exactly at the center, even when removing the space around the vertical rules.
Here is my current test code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

% \SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt,colsep=0pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}|@{}X@{}|@{}}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{0.5\linewidth}|X|}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tblr}{width=1\linewidth, colspec={|X|X|}}
a & b
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{width=1\linewidth, colspec={|Q[wd=0.5\linewidth]|X|},colsep=0pt}
a & b
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{width=1\linewidth, colspec={|Q[wd=0.5\linewidth]|X|}}
a & b
\end{tblr}

% What I am aiming for:
\begin{tblr}{width=1\linewidth, colspec={|Q[wd=0.5\linewidth]|l|X|X}}
a & b & c & d
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


And the output:

I vaguely understand that the middle line does not line up when simply using p{0.5\linewidth} or Q[wd=0.5\linewidth] due to the extra spacing caused by the vertical rules, but even when trying to remove it usin @{} or colsep=0pt, it does not line up with the middle of a simple table with equal column widths.
Trimming the white space also moves the content right next to the rules, which is not what I want.
How can I perfectly size the first column to half the text/linewidth, as illustrated in the final tabular in the example code?

Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--13

Never ignore warnings.  The first problem (which latex is warning about) is that you have tables that are \textwidth wide but indented by 15pt of \parindent so you want \noindent or \centering etc. With that, and just looking at tabularx you get

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}|@{}X@{}|@{}}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{0.5\linewidth}|X|}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

As you see, the rules line up in the first two cases. Each X column is equvalent to a p{0.5\dimexpr\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}  that is half of the space that remains after removing the column padding is allocated to each column.
In the third case the first column is wider as you have p{0.5\textwidth}  so there is \arrayrulewidth for the rule then \tabcolsep space then 0.5\textwidth then \tabcolep then the middle rule.
So to make them all line up without using X in the first column:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}|@{}X@{}|@{}}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|
p{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}|X|}
a & b
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

Although having got that far you could avoid X columns at all and do the whole allocation yourself, which is often prefereable anyway.
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 p{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
a & b
\end{tabular}

Which just needs array package. (If you are not loading array then omit the -3\arrayrulewidth as in the built in tabular vertical rules take no width, they over-print the surrounding space.)

Thanks. So the rules also have a width. I still get a slight offset using your code in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ttngmkmjttzt#d021cd
How did you compile it?
For the length computation, do \dimexpr and \relax act like brackets? i.e. 0.5\dimexpr\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax = 0.5*(\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth) ?

@KIAaze there is an offset in your second one using @{}|@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}|@{}X@{}|@{}  as the @{} move the middle rule, but the others all line up (I used texlive 2024 pdflatex) same on overleaf of course: https://www.overleaf.com/read/trngcqnppdmz#783c48
